# Python Recursive Function not returning list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, recursion

Just practicing some assignments in an algorithms textbook using python3. This function is supposed to read a list/array of integers and return a new list/array of only the even integers. I feel like my implementation is correct but it is not returning the list as I expect.

Here is my function, and a quick test for it. I am printing out the length of the array as it is returned (6), and then printing the length immediately when the function is called (None)

```
def even_array(array1, new_array=[], index=0):
    if index >= len(array1):
        print(len(new_array))
        return new_array
    else:
        if(array1[index] % 2) == 0: #this is an even number
            new_array.append(array1[index])
        even_array(array1, new_array, index + 1)


int_array = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,99,102,104,22]

new_array = even_array(int_array)
print(len(new_array))

new_array = even_array(int_array)
for element in new_array:
    print(element)
```

This is my first post on here, so any feedback on formatting or how much info I should include is appreciated :)

Comment: You're missing a return statement.  For a recursive function, you have to return the result of the function calling itself.

Comment: @gaw89 Yes that was exactly the reason. I added it in and it works now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` case is missing a `return` statement, so the value isn't returned.

```py
def even_array(array1, new_array=[], index=0):
    if index >= len(array1):
        print(len(new_array))
        return new_array
    else:
        if(array1[index] % 2) == 0: #this is an even number
            new_array.append(array1[index])
        return even_array(array1, new_array, index + 1)
```

Side note: don't pass an empty array as a default argument, that's an easy way to introduce hard to debug issues. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941) answer for better clarity.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. That was the issue. I remember seeing something about empty lists as function parameters, so I will definitely have to read through that link.

Comment: @Platrick consider upvoting if it solves your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good, but there are a few issues with the execution.

1. You are missing a return statement in the else branch;
2. You are modifying a list parameter. This will make things hard to follow, as it will retain all changes done by all the recursive calls. This is to be avoided in general.

A possible fix:

```
def even_array(array1, new_array=[], index=0):
    if index >= len(array1):
        print(len(new_array))
        return new_array
    else:
        if(array1[index] % 2) == 0: #this is an even number
            return even_array(array1, new_array + [array1[index]], index + 1)
```

You can do it with `.append` too in this case, since there is nothing else being done after the recursive call. If there were another recursive call for example, you would likely need to have a corresponding `.pop` call. But if possible, avoid mutating list parameters like this.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. That was indeed the issue